# How to force pilon to correct a reference with low coverage mapped reads?

Tags: sam, reference-genome, read-correction

I have mapped some reads to a reference and want to change SNPs in the reference to SNPs found in the reads, even at low coverage. For example, here is a screenshot of one reference in IGV that I would like to correct.

[image]

When I use pilon to try to correct the reference, however, no bases are ever changed, even if using the option `--mindepth 1`.

Here is the call that I am using:

```
java -Xmx100G -jar {params.pilon}\
  --genome {input.ref}\
  --frags {input.bam}\
  --output {params.outname}\
  --changes --fix all,amb,breaks,bases\
  --threads {threads}\
  --mindepth 1
```

How can I use even low-coverage information to correct my reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pilon will not consider fragments that are not proper pairs if the `--frags` option is used to pass the alignment `.bam` file. The reads mapped in the above IGV screenshot are unpaired.

Instead, if you want Pilon to consider *all* reads that map as legitimate and usable for correction, pass the `.bam` file with the `--unpaired` option instead.

To above corrected example would be:

```
java -Xmx100G -jar {params.pilon}\
  --genome {input.ref}\
  --unpaired {input.bam}\
  --output {params.outname}\
  --changes --fix all,amb,breaks,bases\
  --threads {threads}\
  --mindepth 1
```